# Why the paired orbit has the same size here?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929449/how-to-show-that-the-orbits-of-the-action-of-gs-on-s-s-have-lengths-that-are/929595#929595)

On this proof, he just showed that the the paired orbit of (a,b) has the same size, but this seem has nothing to do with the size of corresponding paired orbit of an orbit of Gs on S. 
In addition, how to show when |G| is odd, then we don't have an element of G interchanges a and b?

Answer (score 3):

I posted an answer in the link (to your previous question) by mistake.  I'll copy it here:

Let $G$ act on a set $S$.  The orbits of the induced action of $G$ on $S \times S$ are called the orbitals of $G$.  Fix $s \in S$. It can be shown that if the action of $G$ on $S$ is transitive, then there is a 1-1 correspondence between the orbits of the action of $G_s$ on $S$ and the orbitals of $G$.  The orbital $\Delta:=(s,t)^G$ corresponds to the $G_s$-orbit $\{t: (s,t) \in \Delta \}$.  One way to visualize this is using the tabular representation of relations on $S$: each orbital corresponds to a union of permutation matrices, and the columns corresponding to the nonzero coordinates in row $s$ of an orbital form the corresponding $G_s$-orbit.

An orbital $(s,t)^G$ is said to be self-paired if it equals its transpose $(t,s)^G$.  If this is the case, then some element of $G$ interchanges $s$ and $t$. This element contains the 2-cycle permutation $(s,t)$ and hence has even order.  Thus $G$ also has even order.  Conversely, if $G$ has even order, then by Cauchy's theorem it has an element of order 2, which contains a 2-cycle $(x,y)$. Thus, there exists an orbital $(x,y)^G$ that equals its transpose.  We have shown that $G$ has even order if and only if some orbital is self-paired.  Take the contrapositive, and we get that $G$ has odd order if and only if every orbital is not equal to its transpose.  In particular, for each orbital $\Delta$ of $G$, there is another orbital $\Delta^*$ which is disjoint from $\Delta$ but which has the same order as $\Delta$.  Due to the 1-1 correspondence, these two orbitals give rise to two distinct $G_s$-orbits of the same order.  For example, if $\Delta$ is a union of $k$ permutation matrices, then so is $\Delta^*$, and the two corresponding $G_s$-orbits have $k$ elements each.

Comment: Thanks, but in my mind, even we can build the corresponding from orbitals to orbits, but how to show the same size of orbitals implies the same size of the corresponding orbits?

Comment: Recall that $G$ acts on $S$ transitively. So an orbital contains the same number of elements in each row of its tabular representation. If an orbital is a union of $k$ permutation matrices (i.e., if the orbital has cardinality $k |S|$), then the orbital has $k$ elements in row $s$, and hence the corresponding $G_s$-orbit has $k$ elements.  Thus, two orbitals of the same size correspond to two $G_s$-orbits of the same size.

Comment: Sorry, why do you say Δ is a union of k permutation matrices,I don't know the relation between an orbital with these permutation matrices.

Comment: It can be shown that each orbital $\Delta$ has the same number of elements in each row of its tabular representation and the same number of elements in each column of its tabular representation.  This implies that the 0-1 matrix representing $\Delta$ is the sum of $k$ permutation matrices (for eg, a bipartite graph of the matrix can be constructed and Hall's theorem can be repeatedly invoked to remove perfect matchings).

Comment: A special case would be if $G$ acts on $S$ regularly. In that case $|G|=|S|$ and an orbital corresponds to a single permutation matrix.